# Using UTF-8 string-literal prefixes portably between C++17 and C++20

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++17, c++20, string-literals

I have a codebase written in C++17 that makes heavy use of UTF-8, and the [`u8` string literal introduced in c++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to indicate UTF encoding. However, c++20 changes the meaning of what the `u8` literal *does* in C++ from producing a `char` or `const char*` to a `char8_t` or `const char8_t*`; the latter of which is *not implicitly pointer convertible* to `const char*`.

I'd like for this project to support operating in both C++17 and C++20 mode without breakages; what can be done to support this?

---

Currently, the project uses a `char8` alias that uses the type-result of a `u8` literal:

```cpp
// Produces 'char8_t' in C++20, 'char' in anything earlier
using char8 = decltype(u8' ');
```

But there are a few problems with this approach:

1. `char` is not guaranteed to be unsigned, which makes producing codepoints from numeric values not portable [(e.g. `char8{129}` breaks with `char`, but not with `char8_t`).](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4T9s1Whz3)
2. `char8` is not distinct from `char` in C++17, [which can break existing code, and may cause errors.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PhW4bqfe1)
3. Continuing from point-2, it's not possible to overload `char` with `char8` in C++17 to handle different encodings because they are not unique types.

What can be done to support operating in both C++17 and C++20 mode, while avoiding the type-difference problem?

Comment: Ditch the `u8` prefix, ensure that your sources are saved in UTF-8 (and pass the proper compiler flags to ensure that it undestands that it's in UTF-8), and enable an utf8-aware locale?

Comment: Dropping `u8` would both be a big change, and IMO a step backwards. I'd like to semantically represent UTF-8 encoding in the type to distinguish between ASCII `char` where possible. C++20 makes this possible, just... not portably with C++17 or earlier.

Comment: If `const char8_t*` it not implicitly convertible to `const char*`, can you just explicitly convert it?

Comment: I'd just assume that `char` is UTF-8, and there's no separate ASCII type. But if you want to keep this difference, then the solution for (1) is to use `char8(129)`, and for the rest - a bunch of ad-hoc `#if`s?

Comment: Does the `u8` prefix handle Turkish special characters (16-bit) and Japanese glyphs (24-bit)?  I'm presently using `char32_t` but looking for something "more appropriate".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat wouldn't `char8(129)` result in signed-integer-overflow when `char8` is `char`? I would have thought this would qualify as undefined behavior. If this is well-defined in C++17, then I guess that's an option -- but ad-hoc `#if`s are going to suck (was aiming for a more portable, less-painful option)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: It's UTF-8, which is an encoding of Unicode. All Unicode encodings handle the same stuff because... they're just *encodings* of codepoints.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I think `reinterpret_cast<const char*>` *might* be legal here, since I believe `char` is explicitly allowed to alias other pointers. This wouldn't work within any context that might be `constexpr` though, as `reinterpret_cast` is explicitly forbidden. This would also be quite verbose

Comment: @Human-Compiler: There is no simple macro solution that will magically make all your code work. You have to employ different solutions to specific categories of issues. So you're going to have to go through and get a list of specific cases where problems occur.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm aware there is no macro; I am just looking for input for how this can preserve type-correctness; even if that potentially means implementing a `char8_str` class that acts like a `const char8_t*`

Comment: `char8(129)` is merely implementation-defined (and always works in practice). It's only UB if the overflow happens as a result of calculation, not due to a conversion.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Ironically `char(129)` is well-defined... in C++20 ;)

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's a simple solution, but might actually be the most elegant. If you want to type that as an answer, I'll accept it. Funny enough, though I had considered using `enum class : unsigned char` in C++17, it never occurred to me to just use a basic alias of `unsigned char`. I guess it's unlikely to experience an overload where I have two functions accepting either a `char8_t` or an `unsigned char`, so this should be minimal risk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest simply declaring your own `char8_t` and `u8string` types in pre-C++20 versions to alias `unsigned char` and `basic_string<unsigned char>`. And then anywhere you run into conversion problems, you can write wrapper functions to handle them appropriately in each version.