# C++20 UTF-8 String Literals With Octal Sequences

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++20

While porting legacy code to C++20, I replaced string literals (with expected UTF-8 encoded text) to UTF-8 string literals (the one prefixed with `u8`).

Thereby, I ran into an issue with octal sequences which I used in the past to encode UTF-8 sequences byte for byte:

While
`"\303\274"` was the proper encoding of `ü`,
`u8"\303\274"` ended up in `Ã¼`.

I investigated into this further and found on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Initialization):

> 2. For each [numeric escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape), given `v` as the integer value represented by the octal or hexadecimal number comprising the sequence of digits in the escape sequence, and T as the string literal’s array element type (see the table [above](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Info_table)):
>
>    - If `v` does not exceed the range of representable values of T, then the escape sequence contributes **a single code unit with value `v`**.

(Emphasis mine)

In my own words: In UTF-8 string literals, octal (`\ooo`) and hex (`\xXX`) escape sequences are interpreted as Unicode code points, similar like Unicode sequences (`\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX`).

Hence, this appeared reasonable to me: For UTF-8 string literals, Unicode escape sequences should be favored over the byte-wise octal sequences (I used in the past).

Out of curiosity (and for the purpose of demonstration), I made a small test on coliru and was surprised to see that with `g++ -std=c++20`, the octal sequences still are interpreted as single bytes. The above cite in mind, I came to the conclusion:

**MSVC seems to be correct, and g++ wrong.**

I made an MCVE which I ran in my local Visual Studio 2019:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

void dump(std::string_view text)
{
  const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
  for (unsigned char c : text) {
    std::cout << ' '
      << digits[c >> 4]
      << digits[c & 0xf];
  }
}

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(const char* const text = "\344\270\255");
  DEBUG(dump(text));
  std::cout << '\n';
  DEBUG(const char8_t* const u8text = u8"\344\270\255");
  DEBUG(dump((const char*)u8text));
  std::cout << '\n';
  DEBUG(const char8_t* const u8textU = u8"\u4e2d");
  DEBUG(dump((const char*)u8textU));
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output for **MSVC**:

```
const char* const text = "\344\270\255";
dump(text);
 e4 b8 ad
const char8_t* const u8text = u8"\344\270\255";
dump((const char*)u8text);
 c3 a4 c2 b8 c2 ad
const char8_t* const u8textU = u8"\u4e2d";
dump((const char*)u8textU);
 e4 b8 ad
```

(Please, note that the dump that the dump of the 1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> literal are identical while the second results in UTF-8 sequences by interpreting each octal sequence as Unicode code point.)

The same code run in Compiler Explorer, compiled with **g++ (13.2)**:

```
const char* const text = "\344\270\255";
dump(text);
 e4 b8 ad
const char8_t* const u8text = u8"\344\270\255";
dump((const char*)u8text);
 e4 b8 ad
const char8_t* const u8textU = u8"\u4e2d";
dump((const char*)u8textU);
 e4 b8 ad
```

The same code run in Compiler Explorer, compiled with **clang (17.0.1)**:

```
const char* const text = "\344\270\255";
dump(text);
 e4 b8 ad
const char8_t* const u8text = u8"\344\270\255";
dump((const char*)u8text);
 e4 b8 ad
const char8_t* const u8textU = u8"\u4e2d";
dump((const char*)u8textU);
 e4 b8 ad
```

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rEvqePbP1)

Is my conclusion correct that MSVC does it correct according to the C++ standard, in opposition to g++ and clang?

---

What I found by web search before:

- [C++20 with u8, char8_t and std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56833000/7478597)
- [Using UTF-8 string-literal prefixes portably between C++17 and C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70930072/7478597)

---

Using hex escape sequences instead of octal sequences doesn't change anything: [Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rYY9oac5G).

I preferred the somehow unusual octal sequences as they are limited to 3 digits, no unrelated character may extend them unintendedly — in opposition to hex sequences.

---

Update:

When I was about to file a bug for MSVC, I realized that this was already done:
[escape sequences in unicode string literals are overencoded (non conforming => compiler bug)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/escape-sequences-in-unicode-string-liter/260684)

Comment: On msvc compile with /utf-8 switch and it will work like gcc. Msvc’s default source encoding is a legacy localized encoding (typically Windows-1252) and that is used to interpret the bytes in source code.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/sfj6Mnqvd)'s a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67819605/1387438 (please note this answer works for output well, AFAIK this approach do not work on `std::cin` on any platform). If you follow this instruction use of escape sequences is not needed.

Comment: I suspect the thinking in Redmond is "Yeah, `/utf-8` and `/permissive-` would make the compiler compliant with the standard, but that'd break everyone's code.  So we better err on the side of the *status quo*, *continuity*, and *backwards compatibility* and have the default behavior be legacy code friendly."

Comment: @MarkTolonen Either I'm blinded, looking that MCVE of n.m. (the comment below your) or it works with `/utf8` exactly as without: `0c3H, 0a4H, 0c2H, 0b8H, 0c2H, 0adH`. Btw. one of the intentions of these octal sequences was to make the source code robust against any necessary command line argument... ;-)

Comment: @Eljay `/permissive-` doesn't change anything. (I even believe, I have it by default on my local box - just checked that I have...)

Comment: Note that msvc uses system locale encoding by default. gcc and clang are assume utf-8 encoding. Did you change msvc options so it uses proper encodings? `/utf-8` switch enforces utf-8 in source code and string literals in executable. Anyway you should show compiler options in question.

Comment: `/permissive-` disables Microsoft extensions, and enables standard C++-isms like `not` being a keyword.  I don't think it has impact on encoding.  I was just using it as another example of **default** variance from the standard.  (GCC has it's own variances from the standard, and requires explicit opt-in to be standard compliant.  Microsoft isn't an outlier here.)

Comment: @MarekR I just tried `/utf-8` on my local box. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI `/utf8` is not recognized in your MCVE. Anyway, `/utf-8` doesn't change that as well. (I consider my MCVEs as more illustrative but yours is admittedly more compact.) ;-)

Comment: Editing error, should be /utf-8 (it doesn't change the output).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my own words: In UTF-8 string literals, octal (`\ooo`) and hex (`\xXX`) escape sequences are interpreted as Unicode code points, similar like Unicode sequences (`\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX`).

No, this is incorrect. In UTF-8, a [code unit](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/#code_unit) means an 8-bit unit (= byte), and a Unicode [code point](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/#code_point) is represented by a sequence of one or more code units. Each octal escape sequence corresponds to a single code *unit*, which is different from Unicode escape sequences, which correspond to code *points*.

So GCC and Clang are correct, and MSVC is faulty.

Answer (score 2):

These results are due to a known defect in the MSVC compiler that is described in the ["Semantics of numeric-escape-sequences in UTF-8 literals" section](https://wg21.link/p2029#impact-escapes) of [P2029 (Proposed resolution for core issues 411, 1656, and 2333; numeric and universal character escapes in character and string literals)](https://wg21.link/p2029) as adopted for C++23. That paper clarified the intended behavior for numeric escape sequences in UTF-8 literals (and resolved the related [CWG 1656](https://wg21.link/cwg1656) and [CWG 2333](https://wg21.link/cwg2333) issues in doing so).

[Microsoft's language conformance documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance) does not claim conformance with that paper as of today (2024-01-24).